# Im trying to add hyperlink in a datatable, and they just wont render, Can someone help me with it?

Tags: python, html, datatable, hyperlink, plotly-dash

here, I tried to wrap a hyper link to all sys_id's present in the df using generate_links, I'm trying to display them in the ui as a datatable, but it just wont render

```
def generate_link(sys_id):
    base_url = 'some_url/{sys_id}'
    url = base_url + sys_id
    return f'<a href="{url}"> {sys_id}</a>'

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable', 'children'),
    [Input('refresh-button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('incident-date', 'value')]
)

def data_table(n_clicks, incident_date):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        
        # df=get_servicenow_info()
        df = pd.read_csv('/Users/unraveldata/Documents/servicenow/servicenow/assets/state2.csv')
    
        if incident_date == 'option1':  # Today
            filtered_df = df[df['created_at'].str.startswith(timestamp)]
        elif incident_date == 'option2':  # Last 7 days
            filtered_df = df[df['created_at'] >= seven_days_ago_timestamp]
        elif incident_date == 'option3':  # Last 30 days
            filtered_df = df[df['created_at'] >= thirty_days_ago_timestamp]
            
        filtered_df['sys_id'] = filtered_df['sys_id'].apply(generate_link)
        
        layout = [
                dbc.Col(
                children=[
                    dash_table.DataTable(
                        data=filtered_df.to_dict('records'),
                        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],       
                        page_action='native',    
                        page_size=10,
                        style_table={'overflowX': 'auto'},
                        unsafe_allow_html=True,
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
        return layout
```

here is the what it look like in datatable
 0852031c47e002107622b979316d4355

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide some example rows from the dataframe to help with debugging? I also notice that there's a missing `f` on the string in `generate_link`, which could be related, but might not be the full story.